# '&' Character Breaks Query String

Tags: c#, .net, query-string, special-characters

I have a page that is doing some actions based on the value of a query string. However I recently noticed that this breaks when the Query String contains the '&' character.

I am aware I could write some code that would translate the '&' character on the parent page but I have to believe there is a better way to do this.

Here is an example:
Query string:Exercise Science & Sports Studies
This only returns 'Exercise Science'

Here is the code I have to get the string:

```
string selectedDept = Request.QueryString [ "dept" ];
```

I would prefer not to encrypt the URL as the pages are sometimes linked to directly.

Comment: You need to URL encode the parameters. They should be decoded for you in Request.QueryString automatically.

Comment: use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` and `HttpUtility.UrlDecode`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to encrypt, you need to encode the string before generating the Url.

If you are using MVC you can use:

```
var url = "dept=" + Url.Encode(strDept);
```

Otherwise you can also use:

```
var url = "dept=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strDept);
```

**Update**:

unfortunately, this will generate an ugly URL:

```
dept=Exercise%20Science%20%26%20Sports%20Studies
```

Answer (score 1):

The ampersand (`&`) character is *defined* to separate request parameters, so there is no other way to get it inside such a parameter than to encode it.

You don't need to *encrypt* the parameter, just to *encode* it. A common encoding for this case is the so called [URL encoding](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL-Encoding). The nice thing about this encoding is that normal letters and numbers stay as they are; only special characters are encoded with percent-sign sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `&` character breaks query strings. It is used as a metacharacter to separate the parameters. If you need to include a `&` character in a query parameter, then you have to encode it to `%26`. On ASP.Net, you do this with the `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` method, called on the `Server` object in page scope.

Answer (score 0):

You should encode your parameters, like:
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(myUrl);

Answer (score 0):

The ampersand is used to delimit parameters.

You need to URL encode the parameters. They should be decoded for you in Request.QueryString automatically.